# Bootstrap + Angular: Can't bind to 'bs-target' since it isn't a known property of 'button'

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

i am currently developing an Angular Application and using Bootstrap CSS.
I want to use an Accordion Component which gives me an expandable item for each element i have.
The Bootstrap example works just fine. In the Button i need to assign the right item, otherwise it will expand all items.
The example for such an button is:

```
<button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
    Accordion Item #1
  </button>
```

I have a Problem with the `data-bs-toggle`part.

If i want to assign a part of my Observable it suddenly crashes with the error:
**Can't bind to 'bs-target' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.**
I paste the whole Accordion i am using:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionSpieltage">
    <div class="accordion-item" *ngFor="let spieltagparam of matchdayParams$ | async">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#{{spieltagparam.spieltagid}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          {{ spieltagparam.spieltag}}
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionSpieltage">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you install the types for Bootstrap?

Comment: Be sure that you imported import { NgbAccordionModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'; and  add the module imports: [NgbAccordionModule],

Comment: @BrandonTaylor yes, bootstrap works. Works in general with all the icons etc.

Comment: @NikitaBardakov: thats what i checked as well. I Import it in my component. It's in my node modules but when i want to use the code it prompts the error:``` 'ngb-accordion' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngb-accordion' is an Angular component, then verify that it is included in the '@Component.imports' of this component.
2. If 'ngb-accordion' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@Component.schemas' of this component to suppress this message```